# My app keeps crashing after I added a firebase database I keep getting a compile error with app in android studios

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

Does anyone understand this error message Help Plz

11/28 03:56:03: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.tastebuds/com.example.tastebuds.MainActivity" 
-a       android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 15076 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. 
This behavior can be disabled in     the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" 
settings  page.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tastebuds, PID: 15076

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class   "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file  
"/data/app/com.example.tastebuds-
MuVNPt6cV8GXPEwZSlpcDg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/com.example.tastebuds-MuVNPt6cV8GXPEwZSlpcDg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, 
/system/product/lib]]
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1226)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tastebuds-  
MuVNPt6cV8GXPEwZSlpcDg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/com.example.tastebuds-MuVNPt6cV8GXPEwZSlpcDg==/lib/x86, /system/lib,
/system/product/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
  at  
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication
(CoreComponentFactory.java:49)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1148)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1218)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Process 15076 terminated.

```
    this is my build.gradle file (app)

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
               compileSdkVersion 29
               buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
               defaultConfig {
               applicationId "com.example.tastebuds"
               minSdkVersion 17
               targetSdkVersion 29
               versionCode 1
               versionName "1.0"
               testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
             multiDexEnabled true
           }
           buildTypes {
           release {
                      minifyEnabled false
                      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                      'proguard-rules.pro'
                   }
                      }
  }

   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

try adding

```
<application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

in your manifest because you are using androidx. But if you finished adding it to your manifest, try to `clean project` or `Invalidate caches and restart` your project